# How to setup SDL for g++/gcc on VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

how to fix the line `"${workspaceFolder}/bin/sdl2-config --cflags"` in Tasks.json to link with SDL? Because it shows an error `` g++.exe: error: `.../mainfolder/bin/sdl2-config: Invalid argument ``.

The reason I use the SDL files in `mainfolder/bin` but not the SDL files in `external/SDL2/bin` is because when the project is released, we only need the binary files but not the source codes.

**EXPLORER**

```
mainfolder (it's the ${workspaceFolder})
    .vscode
        c_cpp_properties.json
        tasks.json
    bin
        sdl2-config
        SDL2.dll
    external
        imgui
            ...
        SDL2
            bin
                sdl2-config
                SDL2.dll
            include
            lib
        SDL2_image
    helloworld.cpp
    ...
```

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\codeblocks-20.03mingw-nosetup\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/external/imgui/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",

                // SDL
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/SDL2/include/SDL2",
                "`${workspaceFolder}/bin/sdl2-config --cflags`",  // <-- g++.exe: error: `.../mainfolder/bin/sdl2-config: Invalid argument

                // ImGui
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/imgui",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Are you using the bash shell? ` "`${workspaceFolder}/bin/sdl2-config --cflags`"` is handled by the shell. cmd.exe or powershell won't handle this.

Comment: I was using the run [►] button (Debug C/C++ File) for the file ``"helloworld.cpp"`` on top right of VSCode. I'm a beginner on VSCode. But I found another solution, use CMake in VSCode and it's using a CMakeLists.txt and I succeed to create an SDL Window, I googled this: `Import a CMake project into Visual Studio Code`.